# Azure Job submission fails with 400 complaining about Etag

Tags: rest, azure-iot-hub

### Prologue

I'm trying to create a “ScheduleUpdateTwin” job to Azure IoT hub using the Azure REST API, using Python 2 and the `requests` package.

### Analysis

#### response to the request

I'll start with the `requests` log line (hiding the hubname):

```
DEBUG:urllib3.connectionpool:https://<myhubname>.azure-devices.net:443 "PUT /jobs/v2/j1505904104?api-version=2017-06-30 HTTP/1.1" 400 441
```

Indeed, the `req.status_code` is `400`.

The `req.content` is (mangling the tracking IDs a little):

> {"Message":"ErrorCode:ArgumentInvalid;Error: BadRequest {\"Message\":\"ErrorCode:ArgumentInvalid;Missing or invalid etag for job type ScheduleUpdateTwin. ScheduleUpdateTwin job type is a force update, which only accepts \'*\' as the Etag.\",\"ExceptionMessage\":\"Tracking ID:xxxxxxxxxx8844a48f81e29359ba0279-TimeStamp:09/20/2017 10:41:45\"}","ExceptionMessage":"Tracking ID:xxxxxxxxxxe14888a51434047aef23d0-G:5-TimeStamp:09/20/2017 10:41:46"}

#### response headers

```
{'Content-Length': '441',
 'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
 'Date': 'Wed, 20 Sep 2017 11:10:12 GMT',
 'Server': 'Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0',
 'iothub-errorcode': 'ArgumentInvalid'}
```

#### request headers

The headers of my request (as sent to the Azure API endpoint) are (again, mangling private data):

```
{'Accept': '*/*',
 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate',
 'Authorization': 'SharedAccessSignature '
                  'sr=<myhubname>.azure-devices.net%2Fjobs&skn=<skn>&sig=<sig>&se=<se>',
 'Connection': 'keep-alive',
 'Content-Length': '227',
 'Content-Type': 'application/json',
 'If-Match': '*',
 'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.18.1'}
```

#### request body

Here's the (pretty-printed for posting here, so the Content-Length would be different, obviously) request body:

```
{
 "maxExecutionTimeInSeconds": 3600,
 "updateTwin": {
  "properties": {
   "desired": {
    "version": "5.0.0"
   }
  },
  "tags": {
   "owner": "tzot"
  }
 },
 "jobId": "j1505904104",
 "type": "scheduleUpdateTwin",
 "queryCondition": "deviceId = 'test_rpi_01'"
}
```

#### If-None-Match instead of If-Match

Of course, the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/iothub/) *hints* that `If-None-Match` should be provided, since this is a `PUT`. So I alter my code and send an `If-None-Match: *` instead; the response is a `400` again.

#### Other REST API calls work fine

Please note that other REST API calls, like `devices/{device_id}` work fine for `GET`, `PUT` and `DELETE` operations without an Etag set; same goes for `twins/{device_id}` (`GET`, `PATCH`) and `twins/{device_id}/methods` (`POST`).

#### API Version

The `API` version I use is: `api-version=2017-06-30`

### Epilogue

How do I submit a job to Azure IoT through a REST API call?

### Updates

#### add "etag": "*" in the request JSON

After a suggestion by Rita Han, I added the `"etag": "*"` key to the request body, which became (note: new jobId):

```
{
 "jobId": "j1505986505",
 "maxExecutionTimeInSeconds": 3600,
 "etag": "*",
 "updateTwin": {
  "properties": {
   "desired": {
    "version": "5.0.0"
   }
  },
  "tags": {
   "owner": "tzot"
  }
 },
 "type": "scheduleUpdateTwin",
 "queryCondition": "deviceId = 'test_rpi_01'"
}
```

The result is the same: HTTP 400 status code, with the same content in the response. Tried it with `If-Match: *` in the HTTP request headers, then with `If-None-Match: *`, then with `If-None-Match: blabla`, hoping that no existing ETag would match with “blabla”. All to no avail. The response is the same.

### Solution

The content should include an `etag` property right inside the `updateTwin` value.

Comment: Can you show your request body?

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT I edited the question to include the request body. Thanks for looking into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error information points out:

> Missing or invalid etag for job type ScheduleUpdateTwin.
>   ScheduleUpdateTwin job type is a force update, which only accepts
>   \'*\' as the Etag.

You can modify your request body like this:

```
{
 "maxExecutionTimeInSeconds": 3600,
 "updateTwin": {
  "properties": {
   "desired": {
    "version": "5.0.0"
   }
  },
 "etag":"*",
 },
 "jobId": "j1505904104",
 "type": "scheduleUpdateTwin",
 "queryCondition": "deviceId = 'test_rpi_01'"
}
```

**Update:**

Add python test result:

[image]

Comment: I tried it to no avail. The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/iothub/) isn't clear, but it is suggestive that If-Match, Etag etc should be in the HTTP request headers. Have you got any other link to more relevant documentation?

Comment: So the `etag` should be **inside** the `updateTwin` property, not at the same level as it; that was my mistake. Thank you, Rita.

Comment: @tzot My pleasure to help you. For documentation, you can post comments  [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/iothub/).